# Car Scanner tool and output

Tags: honda, civic, fuel-consumption, scan-tool

[image]I am pretty green in this field. Recently, I have bought a Honda Civic 2007 and planned to investigate its condition out of my curiosity. I bought a OBD-II tool and scanned my car. To my surprise, I found that tool is showing fuel consumption 22ltr/100km which is way more than I expected.
and also few parameters which I cannot interpret easily, I am attaching screen capture of those and hoping if experts can help me to understand the same.

Mostly I am worrying about the average(fuel consumption) and also scan tool says that before 26k odometer some error codes has been removed. I am unsure if I have a good buy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your scanner is only showing you values from the journey in progress - it's showing 0.53km driven at a speed of 4.23km/h. I'd suggest driving it a bit more before worrying. I'd also suggest measuring the actual fuel consumption yourself, then you can see how accurate the measurements are.

Fill up the tank to the brim and reset the 'trip' meter. Drive as normal, then when you need to fill up again, fill to the brim (use the same pump if you're being really pedantic, I don't!), and note down the quantity of fuel used and the distance travelled - from this you can easily calculate the consumption.

Comment: Thanks Nick.. There is also it says "Distance travelled since last code cleared". Does that mean there was some code appeared which was removed earlier.

Comment: Hard to tell, as it also has "Distance travelled (total) 0.53km" at the bottom of your last screenshot, which suggests it doesn't know of anything that happened before you first plugged it in...

Comment: To be honest I'd be very surprised if there had never been any error codes on a car of that age... Go by condition, not by what a cheap scan tool might tell you!

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want accurate fuel consumption values: Fill you tank completely, reset your odometer, drive for a few 100 kilometers, and then fill it again, noting how much gas you put in and how many kilometers you drove to calculate an accurate average.

Momentary fuel consumption can get quite high during acceleration and average is always bad after a cold start. Also the computers aren´t always that accurate.

Second, removed error-codes are quite OK - if an error persists it will pop up again. In fact, tats what you normally do with the odd error code: delete and see if it shows up again.